# How do I Unmarshal the bson from mongo of a nested interface with mgo?

Tags: go, mgo

I have a collection of documents that contain an array of a custom interface type that I have. Example below. What do I need to do to Unmarshal the bson from mongo so I can eventually return a JSON response?

```
type Document struct {
  Props here....
  NestedDocuments customInterface
}
```

What do I need to do to map the nested interfaces to the right structs?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/blob/master/common/bsonutil/converter.go)?

Comment: Not quite, I'd like to take it to a go struct first as to do any processing necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is evident that an interface cannot be instantiated, therefore the `bson` runtime does not know which `struct` has to be used to `Unmarshal` that object. Additionally, your `customInterface` type should be exported (i.e. with capital "C") otherwise it won't be accessible from the `bson` runtime.

I suspect that using an interface implies that the NestedDocuments array may contain different types, all implementing `customInterface`.

If that's the case, I am afraid that you will have to do some changes:

Firstly, `NestedDocument` need to be a struct holding your document plus some information to help the decoder understand what's the underpinning type. Something like:

```
type Document struct {
  Props here....
  Nested []NestedDocument
}

type NestedDocument struct {
  Kind string
  Payload bson.Raw
}

// Document provides 
func (d NestedDocument) Document() (CustomInterface, error) {
   switch d.Kind {
     case "TypeA":
       // Here I am safely assuming that TypeA implements CustomInterface
       result := &TypeA{}
       err := d.Payload.Unmarshal(result)
       if err != nil {
          return nil, err
       }
       return result, nil
       // ... other cases and default
   }
}
```

In this way, the `bson` runtime will decode the whole `Document` but leave the payload as a `[]byte`.

Once you have decoded the main `Document`, you can use the `NestedDocument.Document()` function to get a concrete representation of your `struct`.

One last thing; when you persist your `Document`, make sure that `Payload.Kind` is set to **3**, which represents an embedded document. See the BSON specifications for more details on this.

Hope it is all clear and good luck with your project.